# redirectTo not working when using canActivate guard

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-services

The `redirectTo` property isn't working in my Angular 2 app. I have the following routes in my `app.routing.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/page/1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'page', loadChildren: 'app/modules/page/page.module#PageModule' }
]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Then, in my `page.routing.ts`, I have the following:

```
const pageRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: PageComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
];

export const pageRouting = RouterModule.forChild(pageRoutes);
```

Every time I access the home page it displays the `LoginComponent` for a second, then it disappears. However, it should redirect to the `PageComponent`.

Why isn't that happening? Why the `LoginComponent` is being loaded (even if it's only for a brief second) if the user is already logged in?

Here's my `LoginGuard`:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth.map(auth =>  {
      if (auth === null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }).first();
  }

}
```

**EDIT:** Temporarily, I changed the `LoginComponent` to redirect to the `PageComponent` if a user is logged in. I still wonder, though, why `redirectTo` isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why this is happening, but I believe if you check the LoginGuard before the PageModule loads, it will work.

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/page/1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { 
    path: 'page', 
    // Call the guard before the module is loaded
    canLoad: [ LoginGuard ]
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/page/page.module#PageModule' 
  }
]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

LoginGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {}

  // Add this method to validade the canLoad
  canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.canActivate();
  }  

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth.map(auth =>  {
      if (auth === null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }).first();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You should NOT navigate inside a Guard

This is happening because you call `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` directly from your route guard which initializes a new route navigation on top of the one currently running.
You create a "race" between two navigations; my guess is the one to `/login'` wins because the other one has to lazy load the module (takes some time). But after the loading is done, it changes to that route afterwards, hence the "flashing" login popup.

You should NOT navigate inside a Guard, instead you should always return either a `boolean` (to allow navigate true/false) or a `UrlTree` if you want to redirect/change the route. The Guard returns the value and the router will then change navigation to the provided `UrlTree` for you inside the ongoing/triggered navigation and you won't get any race.

So change your method like this, and it will work correct.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean|UrlTree> {
  return this.af.auth.map(auth =>  {
    if (auth === null) {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
    }
    return true;
  }).first();
}
```

You should see it like this, if you would call `this.router.navigate` in several route guards then the router wouldn't know where to navigate to, by returnin a UrlTree this problem is resolved. See also [a related question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955377/1697459)