# Angular2 run Guard after another guard resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my project I have two guards. AuthGuard and PermissionGuard. I need to first AuthGuard runs and when it resolved and if true the permissionGuard begins but now this guards are running parallel and permissionGuard not working well. the way I used for this issue is that I called the AuthGuard CanActivate method in Permission guard but I think there is a quite better way for doing this.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40590812/6942210) can help you. I think he has the same problem.

Comment: thanks, the answer of question you mentioned is same way I did but as I said I think that better way maybe exists.

Comment: @hosseinahmadi. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: That answer duplicates the existing guard. Can we pass the instance of the other guard into the new one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple canActivate guards all run when first fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589878/multiple-canactivate-guards-all-run-when-first-fails)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've seen it done is to expose the router guards on child routes. Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69i5vo).

```js
{
  path:'', canActivate:[AuthorizationService1], 
    children: [
      {
        path:'', canActivate:[AuthorizationService2],component: HomeComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

guards can't really depend on each other unfortunately. you can do as another person suggested and make one on the parent route and one on a child route, or My preference is just to make a third guard that runs both checks on it's own sequentially so I don't need to muddy up my routes, assuming they're implemented as observables:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthAndPermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authGuard: AuthGuard, permGuard: PermGuard) { }
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authGuard.canActivate(next, state).pipe(
      switchMap(isAuthed => isAuthed ? this.permGuard.canActivate(next, state) : of(false))
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can esaly pass two gurd to routes like this :

```
{
   path:'', canActivate:[AuthorizationGuards1,AuthorizationGuards2] 
}
```

after `AuthorizationGuards1` success `AuthorizationGuards2` activated, the relation between these two guard is st like `AuthorizationGuards1` && `AuthorizationGuards2` conditions.