# Angular 2 How to Apply Multiple Guards with Or-Relationship on the Same Path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

My application allows access to contents based on user roles. I wrote a Router Guard for each role. Some contents allow access for role1 or role2 or role3. How should I write that canActivate declaration in the feature-routing.module.ts file? As I understand, if I write

```
canActivate:[Role1Guard, Role2Guard, Role3Guard]
```

The access will be denied if any of the guards returns false. But in my case, I should allow access if any of the guards returns true. How to do it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The easy solution is to create a guard that takes the 3 roles into account, that's what I do for the moment, Role1or2or3Guard, but I'd love a nicer solution where I can combine my existing guards...

Comment: Yes I thought about this solution too. For one case this will work, and pretty simple to implement. Problem only occurs when you want to generalize it....if you have 5 roles and every combination is possible, you need a robot to write all the guard classes.....

Comment: Yeah I know, I have the exact same problem... Waiting for someone to give you a real solution ;)

Comment: Then could you please vote this question up, so that this question receives attention, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we can do in this case is create a **Master Guard** which will trigger the application guards as per our requirement.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697651/2332159) answer to understand the approach.

Assuming you have gone through it above link, the approach in this case could be as simple as modifying the `data` property in `Route` class.

Something like this -

```
{
    path: "view2",
    component: View2Component,
    //attach master guard here
    canActivate: [MasterGuard],
    //this is the data object which will be used by 
    //masteer guard to execute guard1, guard 2, guard 3 & guard 4
    data: {
        trigger: {
            operator: "OR",
            guards: [
                GUARDS.GUARD1,
                GUARDS.GUARD2,
                GUARDS.GUARD3,
                GUARDS.GUARD4
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And then use `operator` flag to fire all guards accordingly.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write `OrGuard`, something like:

```
class OrGuard() {
  guards: any[];
  constructor(...guards) { this.guards = guards }

  canActivate() {
    return this.guards.some(Boolean);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
canActivate:[new OrGuard(Role1Guard, Role2Guard, Role3Guard)]
```

...just an idea, actual implementation might be different, I didn't try (;

Comment: This won't work if the guards have any dependencies. For example if they need to make HTTP requests. A service or a class factory would work

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, could you please elaborate a little bit? How to do it with service and how to do it with class factory? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I've been super busy.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589878/multiple-canactivate-guards-all-run-when-first-fails?noredirect=1&lq=1 and specifically the answer from tvoloshyn which may provide a solution to your problem.