# Access Routes based on user dynamic permissions in Angular 6 or later

Tags: angular, permissions, routes, authorization

I have applied role-based authorization on the user who is logged in. The JWT token is getting stored in localStorage and routes getting access based on Login and auth.guard.ts.

But in addition to this certain users need to access some components that others with the same role don't. A `JSON` array is defining which routes users can access even after login.

What I have defined to get this done is to check on the `ngOnInit` of the component. If the component is present in the array, it should be allowed to access other `404 page` has to be displayed.

But seems like I am not finding this way as an effective way to do so.

Please suggest any improvisation I can do with illustration. Would like to do everything to be done in the right way.

Comment: Pleas provide a working stackblitz.com with at least part of the code so we can provide you some help.

Comment: You could use another guard. Here‘s an example, how they solved a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40589878

Comment: @insertusernamehere I thought the similar idea, but how will Roleguard know which component or route is accessed to filter out from the list of arrays. note I am new to angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Role validation to a specific route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {   //todo route you want to add validation for
        path: 'route',
        component: Component,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ["Admin"] } //recommend you dont use string here.
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

And then just add these lines to your existing `canActivate` funciton:

```
    let currentUser = User;
    if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
        // role not authorised so redirect to home page
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
    }
```

Read the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).

EDIT:

I recommend you use role routes as its easier to maintain and more consisted however you can just add something like this to your `canActivate` function:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     let stateName: string = state.url.replace("/", "");
     let currentUser = User;
     if (currentUser.routePermissions.includes(stateName)) {
         // route not authorised so redirect to home page
         this.router.navigate(['/']);
         return false;
     }
}
```

Instead of an array maybe use a route object like and just match on actual false match.

```
user.routePermissions = {
    'route1': false
}
```

this will make it easier to maintain as you won't need to update all your users for a new route added.

Comment: this is already been implemented, it is something like I don't have any Role but list of components or routes a user can access.

Comment: i edited my answer to match your needs however i less recommend doing it this way as its a lot of work to maintain

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use `ngx-permissions`, check [this](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions#readme). it works perfectly to give access based on roles in your template or routes, you can load your permissions for each user just after authentication

```
this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);
```

and then you can use them everywhere `canActivate`, `canLoad` to manage access

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'lazy',
   data: {
    permissions: {
     except: 'ADDDMIN',
    }
  },
  canLoad: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
  loadChildren: 'app/lazy-module/lazy-module.module#LazyModule'
},
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
 ],
 exports: [
   RouterModule
 ],
 providers: [
  // CanDeactivateGuard
 ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create different-different Module according to role based authorization on user
and each Molude have one base routing file is there you need to check this module authorized according to user or not with use AuthGuard in routing.