# How to add different permissions to parent and child component?

Tags: angular, routes, permissions

In my angular application routing is implemented as in following example.

User must have *Permission1* permission to open parent component page, and *Permission1* and *Permission2* to view child component. How can I open SecondComponent in view mode without having parent component permission? If that is not possible how can I make new route for viewing *SecondComponent* without having *Permission1*?

````
  {
    path: ':userId', component: MainComponent,
    data: {
      permissions: [Permission1] },
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: FirstComponent,
        data: { reuseRoute: true} },
      { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent,
        data: {
          actionType: ActionType.Edit,
          permissions: [Permission2] },
        canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'second-view/:id', component: SecondComponent,
        data: {
          actionType: ActionType.View,
          permissions: [Permission2] },
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, OverviewGuard] }}]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create multiple auth guard and use them in routing.

Please find the below given reference.

https://www.collegestash.com/using-multiple-guards-route-angular-4/

OR

[Multiple canActivate guards all run when first fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589878/multiple-canactivate-guards-all-run-when-first-fails)

I hope, it answers your question. :)